# How to create a 20x20 grid of tiles in Tkinter then change the color of a specific tile

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

A project I'm working on has me using tkinter to make a gameboard, I haven't ever used tkinter and am unsure how to accomplish what I want.

I have made a 20x20 board of squares using canvas.createRectangle(). but am unable to change the color of a specified piece (lets say the piece at row 8 and column 12 for example.)

I need a way to change a specific tiles fill color and would like this function to be able to take in any coordinate and change the color to any color that is specified.

If there is a better way than using createRectangle please let me know!

What I tried to do was to set tags on each rectangle that was made but I couldn't figure out how to reference each rectangle by using the tags.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#imports
from tkinter import *

#-------------- SET UP THE WINDOW FRAME --------------------------------
class launchScreen(Frame):
    #set the initial size of the window please change width and height
    #it uses these values to determine the window size
    #if you are on a resolution that is not 1920x1080

    def __init__(self, master=None, width=0.5, height=0.4):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        #pack the frame to cover the whole window
        self.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

        # get screen width and height
        ws = self.master.winfo_screenwidth()
        hs = self.master.winfo_screenheight()

        w = ws*width
        h = ws*height
        # calculate position x, y
        x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
        y = (hs/2) - (h/2)
        self.master.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))

        #Make the screen appear on top of everything.
        self.master.overrideredirect(True)
        self.lift()
#Once it has launched do everything in Main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    #set the title of the applicaton window
    root.title('Blokus')

#--------------------- GAME STARTED ----------------------------------------
    def gameStart():

        print("Game Started")
        #get rid of the launch screen elemenets and show the game board
        LaunchScrn.pack_forget()

        #this is where the 20x20 grid is made
        #set up the view of the game board
        def board(view):
            w=view.winfo_width()
            h=view.winfo_height()
            gridWidth = w / 20
            gridHeight = h / 20
            rowNumber = 0
            for row in range(20):
                columnNumber = 0
                rowNumber = rowNumber + 1
                for col in range(20):
                        columnNumber = columnNumber + 1
                        rect = view.create_rectangle(col * gridWidth,
                         row * gridHeight,
                         (col + 1) * gridWidth,
                         (row + 1) * gridHeight,
                         fill = '#ccc')
                         #Sets row, column
                        view.itemconfig(rect, tags=(str(rowNumber), str(columnNumber)))


        #set up the canvas for the game board grid
        viewCanvas = Canvas(root, width=root.winfo_width(), height=root.winfo_height(),bg="#ddd")
        viewCanvas.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH,padx=1,pady=1)

        #when you click on the gameboard this event fires
        def clickOnGameBoard(event):
            if viewCanvas.find_withtag(CURRENT):
                print(viewCanvas.gettags(CURRENT))
                print(type(viewCanvas.gettags(CURRENT)))
                viewCanvas.itemconfig(CURRENT, fill="yellow")
                viewCanvas.update_idletasks()
        #bind an event when you click on the game board
        viewCanvas.bind("<Button-1>", clickOnGameBoard)

        #update the game board after it is done being drawn.
        root.update_idletasks()

        #show the gameboard in the Canvas
        board(viewCanvas)

        #when you click the quit button it returns you to the launch screen
        def clickToQuit(event):
            viewCanvas.destroy()
            label.pack_forget()
            LaunchScrn.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

        #sets up the button for the quit
        quitPath = "images/exit.gif"
        quitImg = PhotoImage(file=quitPath)
        label = Label(root, image=quitImg)
        label.image = quitImg # you need to cache this image or it's garbage collected
        #binds clicking this label to the quit event
        label.bind("<Button-1>",clickToQuit)
        label.pack(side=LEFT)

#------------ GAME ENDED --------------------
    def gameEnd():
        #quits the game
        def quitGame():
            print("Game Ended")
            LaunchScrn.after(3000,root.destroy())
        quitGame()

#---------------------------- LAUNCH SCREEN --------------------------------------------
    LaunchScrn = launchScreen(root)
    LaunchScrn.config(bg="#eee")

    b=Button(LaunchScrn, command=gameStart)
    photo2=PhotoImage(file="images/start.gif")
    b.config(image=photo2, width="300", height="50")
    b.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=X, padx=10, pady=10)

    b=Button(LaunchScrn, command=gameEnd)
    photo4=PhotoImage(file="images/quit.gif")
    b.config(image=photo4, width="300", height="50")
    b.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=X, padx=10, pady=10)

    root.mainloop()
```

## To show the game board:

1. Launch the python file
2. click on the right button (both the buttons are blank)
3. You are looking at the game board.

## Important information about the code:

- This is for an assignment so I had to remove a lot of the other code but this should be enough to show what I need help solving.
- This GUI only shows up correctly on a 1920x1080 resolution but that can be changed by changing the width and height values. (this doesn't pertain to the question but it would be helpful if you would like to run it for your own testing.)
- The images I used on the buttons have been removed
- The button the right shows the gameboard
- The button on the left closes the game
- The fact that is unable to be scaled is not the problem

Thanks so much in advance, to anyone that can help!

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far and how it deviates from your expected behavior.

Comment: I have updated the post to show the code that I have so far. Basically I just need a way to color a square without having to click on that specific tile.

Comment: You need to save the IDs of the rectangles you create, so that you can pass them to `.itemconfig()` later.  A list of lists, or a dictionary with (row, column) tuples as keys would be reasonable choices.

Comment: Posted code is not compilable. What module does `view` and `viewCanvas` originate? Do not assume we know by default. Include all `import` lines. We need a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help, not snippets of sections.

Comment: I have added enough code to make it reproducible, Sorry if it is very bare bones but it's for an assignment and would not feel comfortable posing any of my other group members work.

Comment: @jasonharper How would you save the IDs with the code above, I tried to do that but couldn't get `.itemconfig()` to work with them, so I scraped that idea and tried to add tags that I could reference, but that didn't work out as well.

Comment: Hmmmm... *lauchscreen* or *LaunchScrn*?

Comment: `rect` in your code is the ID of each item as you add it, that's what you need to save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the updated code:

```
#imports
from tkinter import *

#-------------- SET UP THE WINDOW FRAME --------------------------------
class launchScreen(Frame):
    #set the initial size of the window please change width and height
    #it uses these values to determine the window size
    #if you are on a resolution that is not 1920x1080

    def __init__(self, master=None, width=0.5, height=0.4):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        #pack the frame to cover the whole window
        self.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

        # get screen width and height
        ws = self.master.winfo_screenwidth()
        hs = self.master.winfo_screenheight()

        w = ws*width
        h = ws*height
        # calculate position x, y
        x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
        y = (hs/2) - (h/2)
        self.master.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))

        #Make the screen appear on top of everything.
        self.master.overrideredirect(True)
        self.lift()
#Once it has launched do everything in Main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    #set the title of the applicaton window
    root.title('Blokus')
    coordinate={}
    def changecolor(row, column, canvas):
        canvas.itemconfig(coordinate[(row, column)], fill='yellow')

#--------------------- GAME STARTED ----------------------------------------
    def gameStart():
        global coordinate
        print("Game Started")
        #get rid of the launch screen elemenets and show the game board
        LaunchScrn.pack_forget()

        #this is where the 20x20 grid is made
        #set up the view of the game board
        def board(view):
            coordinate={}
            w=view.winfo_width()
            h=view.winfo_height()
            gridWidth = w / 20
            gridHeight = h / 20
            rowNumber = 0
            for row in range(20):
                columnNumber = 0
                rowNumber = rowNumber + 1
                for col in range(20):
                        columnNumber = columnNumber + 1
                        rect = view.create_rectangle(col * gridWidth,
                         row * gridHeight,
                         (col + 1) * gridWidth,
                         (row + 1) * gridHeight,
                         fill = '#ccc')
                         #Sets row, column
                        view.itemconfig(rect, tags=(str(rowNumber), str(columnNumber)))
                        coordinate[(row,col)]=rect
            return coordinate

        #set up the canvas for the game board grid
        viewCanvas = Canvas(root, width=root.winfo_width(), height=root.winfo_height(),bg="#ddd")
        viewCanvas.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH,padx=1,pady=1)

        #when you click on the gameboard this event fires
        def clickOnGameBoard(event):
            if viewCanvas.find_withtag(CURRENT):
                print(viewCanvas.gettags(CURRENT))
                print(type(viewCanvas.gettags(CURRENT)))
                viewCanvas.itemconfig(CURRENT, fill="yellow")
                viewCanvas.update_idletasks()
        #bind an event when you click on the game board
        viewCanvas.bind("<Button-1>", clickOnGameBoard)

        #update the game board after it is done being drawn.
        root.update_idletasks()

        #show the gameboard in the Canvas
        coordinate=board(viewCanvas)
        changecolor(1, 2, viewCanvas)

        #when you click the quit button it returns you to the launch screen
        def clickToQuit(event):
            viewCanvas.destroy()
            label.pack_forget()
            LaunchScrn.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

        #sets up the button for the quit
        quitPath = "images/exit.gif"
        quitImg = PhotoImage(file=quitPath)
        label = Label(root, image=quitImg)
        label.image = quitImg # you need to cache this image or it's garbage collected
        #binds clicking this label to the quit event
        label.bind("<Button-1>",clickToQuit)
        label.pack(side=LEFT)




#------------ GAME ENDED --------------------
    def gameEnd():
        #quits the game
        def quitGame():
            print("Game Ended")
            LaunchScrn.after(3000,root.destroy())
        quitGame()

#---------------------------- LAUNCH SCREEN --------------------------------------------
    LaunchScrn = launchScreen(root)
    LaunchScrn.config(bg="#eee")

    b=Button(LaunchScrn,text='start', command=gameStart)
    #photo2=PhotoImage(file="images/start.gif")
    #b.config(image=photo2, width="300", height="50")
    b.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=X, padx=10, pady=10)

    b=Button(LaunchScrn, text='end',command=gameEnd)
    #photo4=PhotoImage(file="images/quit.gif")
    #b.config(image=photo4, width="300", height="50")
    b.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=X, padx=10, pady=10)

    root.mainloop()
```

Basically, I defined a function called `changecolor`. I also had an example call of that function at line 88. As for the problem of accessing the tiles, I added two lines in your `board` function so that it stores all the created tile in a dictionary. The keys of that dictionary is a tuple `(row, column)`, starts with zero. Also, because I don't have the pictures you use for the buttons, I changed them to texts so that I can run the script. Feel free to change them back.

Comment: I think you need to figure out a way to access your canvas outside your `gameStart` function. You can either make it a global variable, return it, or make your `gameStart` function inside a class.

Comment: This is perfect it does exactly what I need and further along into the integration I'll look into making it a global variable if the need arises. Thank you so much!